# What does this XSLT code do?

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

What does this do?
Am I correct to think that this XSLT code doesn't do anything?

```
....
<xsl:template match="/*[1]">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
....
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a template matching the root element of any name and then applying templates to all child nodes of the root element. I wouldn't call that "doesn't do anything", although the built-in templates would suffice to do the same for the root element and other things so the `...` are crucial to tell whether the template is needed.

Comment: By "doesn't do anything" I mean - root element is selected but since <xsl:apply-templates /> doesn't contain a name attribute - such template doesn't produce any results.

Comment: `<xsl:apply-templates/>` is a short form for `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>` so it processes all child nodes of the root element. It then depends on the other templates what happens with the child nodes, the built-in templates would keep processing up until text nodes are output.